# Is there a way to bulk download files in Jive via API or script?

Tags: export, batch-processing, jive

We have to extract almost 1,000 documents for a divestiture.  Doing it by clicking is going to take a long time.  I know Jive has an API, but I can find anything that would let us download multiple files from multiple groups.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Sure. Use /contents/{contentID} to grab a document.

There's more detail in the [Document Entity Section](https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/cloud/rest/DocumentEntity.html) of the [Jive REST API Documentation](https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/cloud/rest/index.html).

You might find your list of documents to retrieve by using the [Search methods of the API](https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/cloud/rest/SearchService.html#searchContents(List%3CString%3E,%20List%3CString%3E,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20String,%20int,%20int,%20String,%20boolean,%20String)). Here's a curl example:

```
curl -v -u <username:password> https://<url>/api/core/v3/search/contents?filter=search(<search term>)
```

Also, just so you know, there is an active [Jive Developer Community](https://community.jivesoftware.com/community/developer) where questions like this are likely to get more eyeballs. And, as a start to Development with Jive in general, check out https://developer.jivesoftware.com/